# How can I insert data without id.where id is autoincrement in table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, for-loop

I am trying to insert data as an array in a table.where in table id is primary key and auto increment. But when I am inserting data, id is not increasing table and remaining fields are not inserting. I need to insert below sample data

```
data::
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [nric] => anonymous
            [id] => 13
            [fullname] => anonymous
            [gender] => m
            [password] => anonymous
            [address] => 
            [postcode] => 
            [state] => 
            [contact1] => 
            [email] => nomail
            [expirydate] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [nric] => dhoni1234
            [id] => 323
            [fullname] => dhoni
            [gender] => m
            [password] => dhoni1234
            [address] => ntg
            [postcode] => 
            [state] => 
            [contact1] => 
            [email] => dhoni@gmail.com
            [expirydate] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [nric] => dhoni123
            [id] => 324
            [fullname] => dhoni
            [gender] => m
            [password] => dhoni123
            [address] => ntg
            [postcode] => 
            [state] => 
            [contact1] => 
            [email] => dhoni@gmail.com
            [expirydate] => 
        )
```

and below is my code insert into object_data table where in that table id is autoincrement. when i write below query it is just insert array[0] data .not inserting the remaing data

```
$jfile = file_get_contents('php://input');
$final_res = json_decode($jfile, true) ;
$data =  $final_res['users'];

for($x=0; $x<count($data); $x++){

  $sql ="INSERT INTO `object_data` ( `description`, `type`, `owner`) VALUES ('".$data[$x]['email']."','usr','6')

   ";
      $update2 = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
}
```

id is autou increment in table.column description (value:email) has more data but only one value is inerting.please help me to sort out this.id is autou increment in table.column description (value:email) has more data but only one value is inerting.please help me to sort out this

Comment: but when i write the above query the data inserting like                          id=0 description=nomail thats it .but i have more mails in array

Comment: That is probably because it's not really auto increment. You have to set it in the DB to be that way.  The query I put will show the SQL to create the table, It should say `auto increment` somewhere in there.

Comment: yes id is auto increment in table

Comment: no am not getting any error. but only first record of array is inserting and id is inserting as 0 .

Comment: in table last id is 265 .so when i insert new records it should be from 266 but .with my query it is inserting id as 0 and inserting only one row

Comment: from above array i need to insert email to object_data .soo in that array have 4 emails .but when i execute that query only first email is inserting .remaining mails are not inserting .and the id also not inserting

Comment: $sql ="INSERT INTO `object_data` ( `obj_id`,`description`, `type`, `owner`) VALUES ('default','".$data[$x]['email']."','usr','6'        i tried like this but bot working ..id should be increment from last id .if last id is 265 then the data should be inserted from 266

Comment: Can you share your create table statement from MySql?

Comment: @PauloHgo Apparently not as I already asked them to run `SHOW CREATE TABLE object_data`, but I did delete that comment.  I'm pretty much done with this one.  I only a dozen comments on here. and the OP ignored most of them like running a query to get the current AI value etc.

Comment: @PauloHgo   CREATE TABLE `object_data` (
  `obj_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `type` char(4) DEFAULT 'none',
  `title` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` char(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `owner` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `create_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_update` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `import_id` char(50) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: Your table does not have a field with auto increment. Your field `obj_id` does not autoincrement according to the create statement and it defaults to zero.

Comment: @PauloHgo   sorry this is the right syntax for create table CREATE TABLE object_data(`create_date` VARCHAR(20), `description` VARCHAR(128), `import_id` VARCHAR(50), `last_update` VARCHAR(20),
 `obj_id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, `owner` INTEGER, `title` VARCHAR(70), `type` VARCHAR(4) );